# How to perform a rectangular hit test in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, hittest

I have WYSIWYG style javascript interface that allows  a designer to create rectangular regions to generate a document server side.  It is important that these regions do not overlap.

I was wondering what is the single most efficent way to perform a hit test on 2 rectangular regions, there could potentially be hundreds, so efficency is a high priority.

I want to implement the same functionality in Javascript client side, and PHP server side, so an algorithm / PDL  snippet would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use some smart data structure, such as an [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), or a [Quad Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).